# Monitoring server bandwidth

Tags: linux, bandwidth

I want to collect bandwidth usage statistics on my linux server. 
What I want to do, is to write a function (probably will use php exec) that will return the number of bytes, and then store it in DB.

I had tried several methods, but all return complex data.
Is there a method to get simple bandwidth usage in bytes for the server. 
I don't need to know which ip or service using it.
I need only in going and out going usage.

Comment: Use `ifconfig` command for TX and RX bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this will work for you.

This will list the received bytes for eth0

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep 'RX b' | sed 's/:/ /g' | awk '{print $3}'
```

This will list the sent bytes for eth0

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep 'RX b' | sed 's/:/ /g' | awk '{print $8}'
```

If you need for other interfaces you can change the name.

Comment: This is great, but it gives me the total transmitted.
Is there a way to get current transmitted on total over the last X time? Or the only way is to get delta over time?

Comment: The amount of data per second must bae implemented at the level of the visualization program : grafana have a derivative function.